Error on griddb-python installation through Anaconda, Jupyter Notebooks, & pip in MacOS
I'm trying to install the griddb-python library in my computer to connect to a GridDB database.
I'm using an M2 Mac version Sonoma 14.5.
My Python installation was through Anaconda and I have had no issues installing other packages via pip/conda and Jupyter Notebooks.
I read that the latter doesn't support griddb-python, so I tried with pip
pip install griddb-python
I'm getting the following error at execution
Collecting griddb-python
  Using cached griddb_python-0.7.6.tar.gz (52 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: griddb-python
  Building wheel for griddb-python (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [45 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      The [wheel] section is deprecated. Use [bdist_wheel] instead.
      running build
      running build_ext
      building '_griddb_python' extension
      swigging src/griddb.i to src/griddb_wrap.cpp
      swig -python -DSWIGWORDSIZE64 -c++ -outdir . -Isrc -o src/griddb_wrap.cpp src/griddb.i
      creating build
      creating build/temp.macosx-11.1-arm64-cpython-310
      creating build/temp.macosx-11.1-arm64-cpython-310/src
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/aleja/anaconda3/include -arch arm64 -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/aleja/anaconda3/include -arch arm64 -Iinclude -Isrc -I/Users/aleja/anaconda3/include/python3.10 -c src/AggregationResult.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-11.1-arm64-cpython-310/src/AggregationResult.o -std=c++0x
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/aleja/anaconda3/include -arch arm64 -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/aleja/anaconda3/include -arch arm64 -Iinclude -Isrc -I/Users/aleja/anaconda3/include/python3.10 -c src/Container.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-11.1-arm64-cpython-310/src/Container.o -std=c++0x
      src/Container.cpp:22:84: warning: field 'mContainer' will be initialized after field 'mContainerInfo' [-Wreorder-ctor]
          Container::Container(GSContainer *container, GSContainerInfo* containerInfo) : mContainer(container),
                                                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                                                         mContainerInfo(NULL)
      src/Container.cpp:34:26: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wsign-compare]
              for (int i = 0; i< containerInfo->columnCount; i++) {
                              ~^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      src/Container.cpp:53:26: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wsign-compare]
              for (int i = 0; i< mContainerInfo->columnCount;i++) {
                              ~^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      src/Container.cpp:367:27: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wsign-compare]
              for (int i = 0; i < mContainerInfo->columnCount; i++) {
                              ~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      4 warnings generated.
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/aleja/anaconda3/include -arch arm64 -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/aleja/anaconda3/include -arch arm64 -Iinclude -Isrc -I/Users/aleja/anaconda3/include/python3.10 -c src/ContainerInfo.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-11.1-arm64-cpython-310/src/ContainerInfo.o -std=c++0x
      src/ContainerInfo.cpp:89:48: error: non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'int' to 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing]
              mContainerInfo = {containerName, type, propsCount, columnInfoList, rowKeyAssigned};
                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~
      src/ContainerInfo.cpp:89:48: note: insert an explicit cast to silence this issue
              mContainerInfo = {containerName, type, propsCount, columnInfoList, rowKeyAssigned};
                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~
                                                     static_cast<size_t>( )
      src/ContainerInfo.cpp:105:30: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wsign-compare]
                  for(int i = 0; i < mContainerInfo.columnCount; i++) {
                                 ~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      src/ContainerInfo.cpp:227:30: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wsign-compare]
                  for(int i = 0; i < mContainerInfo.columnCount; i++) {
                                 ~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      src/ContainerInfo.cpp:240:31: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wsign-compare]
                  for (int i = 0; i < columnInfoList.size; i++) {
                                  ~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      3 warnings and 1 error generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for griddb-python
  Running setup.py clean for griddb-python
Failed to build griddb-python
Installing collected packages: griddb-python
  Running setup.py install for griddb-python ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Running setup.py install for griddb-python did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [46 lines of output]
      running install
      /Users/aleja/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_ext
      building '_griddb_python' extension
      swigging src/griddb.i to src/griddb_wrap.cpp
      swig -python -DSWIGWORDSIZE64 -c++ -outdir . -Isrc -o src/griddb_wrap.cpp src/griddb.i
      creating build
      creating build/temp.macosx-11.1-arm64-cpython-310
      creating build/temp.macosx-11.1-arm64-cpython-310/src
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/aleja/anaconda3/include -arch arm64 -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/aleja/anaconda3/include -arch arm64 -Iinclude -Isrc -I/Users/aleja/anaconda3/include/python3.10 -c src/AggregationResult.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-11.1-arm64-cpython-310/src/AggregationResult.o -std=c++0x
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/aleja/anaconda3/include -arch arm64 -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/aleja/anaconda3/include -arch arm64 -Iinclude -Isrc -I/Users/aleja/anaconda3/include/python3.10 -c src/Container.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-11.1-arm64-cpython-310/src/Container.o -std=c++0x
      src/Container.cpp:22:84: warning: field 'mContainer' will be initialized after field 'mContainerInfo' [-Wreorder-ctor]
          Container::Container(GSContainer *container, GSContainerInfo* containerInfo) : mContainer(container),
                                                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                                                         mContainerInfo(NULL)
      src/Container.cpp:34:26: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wsign-compare]
              for (int i = 0; i< containerInfo->columnCount; i++) {
                              ~^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      src/Container.cpp:53:26: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wsign-compare]
              for (int i = 0; i< mContainerInfo->columnCount;i++) {
                              ~^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      src/Container.cpp:367:27: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wsign-compare]
              for (int i = 0; i < mContainerInfo->columnCount; i++) {
                              ~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      4 warnings generated.
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/aleja/anaconda3/include -arch arm64 -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/aleja/anaconda3/include -arch arm64 -Iinclude -Isrc -I/Users/aleja/anaconda3/include/python3.10 -c src/ContainerInfo.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-11.1-arm64-cpython-310/src/ContainerInfo.o -std=c++0x
      src/ContainerInfo.cpp:89:48: error: non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'int' to 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing]
              mContainerInfo = {containerName, type, propsCount, columnInfoList, rowKeyAssigned};
                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~
      src/ContainerInfo.cpp:89:48: note: insert an explicit cast to silence this issue
              mContainerInfo = {containerName, type, propsCount, columnInfoList, rowKeyAssigned};
                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~
                                                     static_cast<size_t>( )
      src/ContainerInfo.cpp:105:30: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wsign-compare]
                  for(int i = 0; i < mContainerInfo.columnCount; i++) {
                                 ~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      src/ContainerInfo.cpp:227:30: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wsign-compare]
                  for(int i = 0; i < mContainerInfo.columnCount; i++) {
                                 ~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      src/ContainerInfo.cpp:240:31: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wsign-compare]
                  for (int i = 0; i < columnInfoList.size; i++) {
                                  ~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      3 warnings and 1 error generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> griddb-python

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.

I'm thinking, maybe downgrading to another Python version will solve it?
Thank you very much in advance!

Please show the full error message of your pip install. I am also confused: Are you trying to install griddb-python or the GridDB Server. You are mentioning both in your question. One with a pip error message and for the other you are saying you don't know how to install it. Make sure to only ask one question

Oh my bad, I misread and thought that installing GridDB Server could be a solution for the pip issue. I posted the full error too, thanks

Try doing export CPPFLAGS="-Wno-c++11-narrowing" prior to your pip install command.

I did it and CPPFLAGS="-Wno-c++11-narrowing" showed as an environment variable, however, the pip error persisted
